# How i can put Edittext value into textfield in webview using javascript in android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

i want to put the value that the user entered in the Edittext in a textField of a website that opened via Webview

Basically what i'm trying to do is

-Two editText (user and pass)
send the values to webview textfield then hit login automatically

that's the code of overriding onPageFinished method

```
   @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                "document.getElementById('m_login_email').value ='emailfromAndroidEdittext'; " +
                "})()");

                view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                "document.getElementById('m_login_password').value = 'passwordfromAndroidEdittext'; " +
                "})()");
        view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                "document.getElementsByClassName('_54k8 _52jh _56bs _56b_ _28lf _56bw _56bu')[0].click();" +
                "})()");
```

so how i can change emailfromAndroidEdittext and passwordfromAndroidEdittext to the values that the user entered in the Edittext in the app ?

What i tried

```
   @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {
    String test="hi";
    view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
            "document.getElementById('m_login_email').value =test"; " +
            "})()");

                view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                "document.getElementById('m_login_password').value = 'passwordfromAndroidEdittext'; " +
                "})()");
        view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                "document.getElementsByClassName('_54k8 _52jh _56bs _56b_ _28lf _56bw _56bu')[0].click();" +
                "})()");
```

So in order to javascript read the values, it need to be declared as `var` not `String`

tested on chrome console

```
var test="hi";
document.getElementById('m_login_email').value =test
```

Worked but it's javascript not java so var will not work and if i find a workaround for string to var,i can't put the edittext value in the test variable

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your onPageFinished (this is example only for email field):

```
String test="hi";  //Replace here the text from EditText

myWebView.loadUrl("javascript: (function(){document.getElementById('m_login_email').value ='" + test + "';})();");
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, i test it before, i test many things in that line, include adding %s but nothing work, the textfield in the webview is always empty

Comment: @AsmaAbdelhedi : I have edited my reply. Please try it and let me know.

Comment: Also, while testing, keep it minimal, as in, just test one thing at a time. Comment the rest of the code in onPageFinished except the above code which you'll be testing

Comment: i can't **Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.**